# MySQL calculate last 1 year record

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to calculate the sum of certain columns for a table. Sum of exactly last 1 year. So daily calculation may needed for a set of rows. I was using the following MySQL Query to get older record.

```
//php variable
$timezoneName = timezone_name_from_abbr("PST");
date_default_timezone_set("$timezoneName");
$now = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

SELECT col1,col2 FROM table1
WHERE modificationDate < '$now' - INTERVAL 1 YEAR
```

Here am using PHP variable for setting time to PST timezone. Otherwise I may have used now() function of MySQL.

My challenge is, old records are not deleting from DB and each day the list of old records are increasing. So I want a query to get 1 year old and greater than (1 Year and 1 Day older) records.

I tried like this, but not working

```
SELECT col1,col2 FROM table1
WHERE (modificationDate < '$now' - INTERVAL 1 YEAR) 
AND (modificationDate >= ('$now' - INTERVAL 1 DAY) - INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
```

Any solution?

Thanks

Comment: What type of field is `modificationDate`? Because you could also try `SELECT col1, col2 FROM table1 WHERE YEAR(modificationDate) = 2014`

Comment: You query is fine. What is your data and what is the fail?

Comment: @GerbenJacobs: its datetime field. col1 and col2 are unique ids of those old records

Comment: @AlmaDo: am getting 2 year old data as well. But then those I don't want

Comment: @bansi: That I already mentioned, for getting PST timezone

Comment: @bansi never do that (timezone doesn't matter): this will force MySQL to evaluate `NOW()` for __each__ row, thus, making key impossible to use (if it exists)

Comment: @vTp well, `select (curdate() - interval 1 day) - interval 1 year;` is `2013-03-16` for me (fine as expected). So may be problem lies within your `$now` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At-last I got the desired output with the following logic.

```
$timezoneName = timezone_name_from_abbr("PST");
date_default_timezone_set("$timezoneName");
$lastYear = date("Y-m-d",strtotime("-1 year"));

SELECT col1,col2 FROM table1
WHERE modificationDate LIKE '$lastYear%';
```

Now am able to get particular older data

Thanks all, for your valuable comments.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

> UPDATE table SET date = DATE_ADD(date, INTERVAL 1 YEAR)